# Only allow access to html web page from a specific referrer

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I want to make this page "http://example.com/dashboard/index.html"
only accessable from this page "http://example.com/auth/sign-in.html"

How to make this possible ?

Note:
Apache Version: 2.4.56

Comment: I hope you're also implementing authentication logic instead of just using [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)

Comment: This is not a good approach. If the user refreshes the page, the referer will no longer be set.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=http://example.com/auth/sign-in.html
RewriteRule ^dashboard/index\.html$ - [F]
```

If `/dashboard/index.html` is requested, but the HTTP `Referer` header is *not* `http://example.com/auth/sign-in.html` (exact string match) then respond with a 403 Forbidden.

I have answered quite literally, but this does raise some questions/concerns:

- Is `/dashboard/index.html` also accessible via `/dashboard/` only? (`index.html` looks like the directory index). (But why are you using `index.html` in the URL?)
- Why are you not seemingly using/forcing HTTPS?
- Have you canonicalised the hostname prior this rule? (Although this rule should arguably be first.) ie. Is your site also accessible via the www subdomain?

Taking the above points into consideration may require some changes to this rule.

*Additional warning:* The `Referer` header isn't necessarily reliable since the client can suppress it (in interests of "privacy"). So you could find that legitimate users are still blocked. And the `Referer` header can be faked, so external requests could potentially bypass this "security".